# HTML entities not rendering correctly on mobile browser

Tags: utf-8, fonts, character-encoding, html-entities

We are using the font [Proxima Nova](https://www.marksimonson.com/fonts/view/proxima-nova). Somehow on mobile browsers (works fine on desktop), some HTML entities do not render correctly.
Ex `nbsp` renders as `É`, `'` renders as `Õ`.

Has it something to do with the font itself? We are using UTF-8.

The issue happens on Iphone 13 , OS 15.5, safari and chrome

Comment: Which mobile browser in which version on which OS? Describe details on how one of us is able to reproduce it. On the other hand: why using HTML entities when your text is UTF-8 encoded already? Use the characters directly. `'` is not an entity - did you mean `apos`?

Comment: It certainly is not an issue with the font.

Comment: @AmigoJack Thank you. I have updated the question and added the OS version. Some of the content on the site are immigrated, thats why there are entities like nbsp; .  And it works when I remove Proxima Nova.

Comment: @PeterConstable Is there anyway I can debug this kind of issue and track down the cause?   I havent`t encountered  issues like this before. Thanks in advance